# C# Stack Array, Push method pushes the value to ALL entries

Tags: c#, arrays

I create a stack array and initialize the first element like this:

```
Stack[] snowmen = new Stack[numberOfOperations+1];
snowmen[0] = new Stack();
```

I then iterate through the array and want to perform 2 things:

- Copy the stack from a specific index to the i-th position of the array
- Push/Pop an integer from the new i-th stack

code for that:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfOperations; i++)
{
    . . .

    else if (addSnowball == 0)
    {
        snowmen[i] = new Stack();
        snowmen[i] = snowmen[copySnowmanNr];
        snowmen[i].Pop();
    }
    else
    {
        snowmen[i] = new Stack();
        snowmen[i] = snowmen[copySnowmanNr];
        snowmen[i].Push(addSnowball);
    }

    . . .
}
```

If I call the push or pop method now, EVERY stack in my array will be changed, not only the i-th stack, which may tell me that my copies all refer to the same storage location. Am I right, what am I making wrong, what can I do?

Comment: You don't need `s[i] = new Stack()` if in the next line you're overwriting s[i]. Also in the `for` loop you shouldn't loop i over `numberOfOperations` as it may be bigger than the size of your array, unless you have other strong check elsewhere; even if your init conicides in size you should still iterate over the array.Length instead. Otherwise this code looks legit, the issue must be elsewhere

Comment: But you are looping through every item in your array, so unless the conditions you're checking (to determine if you're going to push/pop) are changing somewhere in this `for` loop, then the same `if\else` block will be hit for every item.

Comment: I tried that earlier, always got a nullReference exception, now it works, also fixed an error in my for loop interating out of bound. But that still does not change the fact I push on every stack.

Comment: this is odd          ```snowmen[i] = new Stack();
        snowmen[i] = snowmen[copySnowmanNr];```   you assign a new stack, then immediately discard it

Comment: Ok so what does that mean ? My goal is to have 'int numberOfOperations' independent stacks in my stack array. If I push/pop and item from stackarray[i], I just want that to happen on stack with that index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that you are referring to the same stack. The following line copies the reference to the stack from the `copySnowmanNr` index to the `i` index.

```
snowmen[i] = snowmen[copySnowmanNr];
```

To create a copy of the actual stack, do the following:

```
snowmen[i] = new Stack(snowmen[copySnowmanNr]);
```

And as others have mentioned, your `snowmen[i] = new Stack();` statement is unnecessary.

**EDIT:** As OP has pointed out in his answer, the above creates a reversed Stack. This is because it builds the new one by simply iterating over the old one. There is a Clone method which creates a shallow copy of the Stack in the correct order:

```
snowmen[i] = (Stack)snowmen[copySnowmanNr].Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

If other people may have the same problem, I want to add something:

if you do it like the answer of the question:

```
snowmen[i] = new Stack(snowmen[copySnowmanNr]);
```

the items of the new stack are reversed, I have just found out that I can fix that with:

```
snowmen[i] = (Stack)snowmen[copySnowmanNr].Clone();
```

I don't know exactly why I have to typcast it with Stack, if not there will be an error, I think it has something to do with the items of a stack which are of the 'Object' type.